# Apache Pig , programe run issues

Tags: apache-pig

i am new to Pig programming,

I just tried to load the data using 'load; statement as

```
A = LOAD 'sample' Using PigStorage(':') as (name:charrarray,word:chararray);
```

My input-sample will look like below

```
ram:how are you
sam:ya i am fine
```

but output look as follows

```
ram,how are you
sam,ya i am fine
```

not delimited by : can you please tell why?

Answer (score 1):

If you used **DUMP** command to the print the output yes that's the expected behavior in pig. DUMP command will always print the output with **','** as delimiter by default.

If you want to print your output with **':'** as delimiter, use like this

```
STORE A INTO '<output folder>' USING PigStorage('<delimiter>');

STORE A INTO 'myoutput' USING PigStorage(':');
```

Inside **myoutput** folder check the file name starts with part*